# How can i customise an EditText Box to just allow currency?

Tags: java, android, validation, input, currency

i'm new to development and i'm just starting my journey into the daunting world of validation. So far i've had it easy and been able to restricted the inputtype just with these two lines: *android:inputType="phone" android:digits="1234567890."*

Now i want to try and stop my user from entering digits past two decimal places. I think i either need to be working with an **InputFilter or using onTextChange** to check for use of the decimal and digits thereafter( alas i don't have a clue how i would go about doing that either). I've got no experience with either of these and i'm having a hard time finding examples online that i can understand, If someone could tell me where to start that would be really appreciated, i think i'm on the right track but im not even sure how i'd go about checking characters let alone restricting them. Any answers welcome, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a class that implements TextWatcher

```
class CurrencyFormatterTextWatcher implements TextWatcher {

   @Override
   public synchronized void afterTextChanged(Editable text) {
        // [...] do your formatting here; beware that each 
        // change to the text value will fire another textchanged event
   }
}
```

then register it as a listener for textchanged events fired by your targeted EditText:

```
currencyFormatter = new CurrencyFormatterTextWatcher();
currencyEditText.addTextChangedListener(currencyFormatter);
```

Comment: Thanks very much, but i'm still trying to figure out what the formatting would look like. if i use .getText within will it just get each new character or the whole string? probably the whole string in which case how do i cycle through characters? and then when i find i have too many characters after the decimal what do i do to change that extra character to "" without effecting the whole box? Also maybe it would be possible to use beforeTextChange to prevent it from entering the character? not sure if that would be a better approach, you've given me alot to think about :)

Comment: I'd suggest checking documentation about NumberFormat class and subclasses (http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html) for your formatting duties. About TextWatcher interface, *beforeTextChanged()* and *onTextChanged()* give more info about the changes being made to the EditText text, but as the docs state, you *must* not do further changes to it; you can override those method in your implementing class to store state data, and then make your changes in the *afterTextChanged* method.